Mismatch in country boundaries and tiles to extract GFC Hansen forest change data
I'm working with R to visualize forest change in Myanmar, but have struggled with the extraction of GFC based on country boundaries.
After setting the country code, I have defined the area of interest:
library(raster)
library(gfcanalysis)

code <- "MMR" 

aoi <- getData("GADM", country = code, level = 0)

The problem occurs when I try to calculate which tiles of GFC data rea needed to cover the area of MMR, returning the following error and leading to a crs mismatch between the area of interest and the tiles to be extracted for analysis:
tiles <- calc_gfc_tiles(aoi)


Warning:
In calc_gfc_tiles(aoi) :
aoi and gfc do not have identical crs. aoi will be reprojected for analysis,
but may not overlap with results when plotting


I have tried to ensure aoi and gfc have the same CRS. Even without a manual user input the wkt component is WGS 84 in both cases:
st_crs(aoi)
Coordinate Reference System:
  User input: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
  wkt:
GEOGCRS["unknown",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        ID["EPSG",6326]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        ID["EPSG",8901]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["longitude",east,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]],
        AXIS["latitude",north,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]]]


> st_crs(tiles)
Coordinate Reference System:
  User input: +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs 
  wkt:
BOUNDCRS[
    SOURCECRS[
        GEOGCRS["unknown",
            DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
                ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
                ID["EPSG",6326]],
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8901]],
            CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                AXIS["longitude",east,
                    ORDER[1],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                        ID["EPSG",9122]]],
                AXIS["latitude",north,
                    ORDER[2],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                        ID["EPSG",9122]]]]],
    TARGETCRS[
        GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
            DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
                ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
                    ORDER[1],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
                    ORDER[2],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            ID["EPSG",4326]]],
    ABRIDGEDTRANSFORMATION["Transformation from unknown to WGS84",
        METHOD["Geocentric translations (geog2D domain)",
            ID["EPSG",9603]],
        PARAMETER["X-axis translation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8605]],
        PARAMETER["Y-axis translation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8606]],
        PARAMETER["Z-axis translation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8607]]]]

I have also tried setting an identifier in advance to ensure that the user input is uniform through
crs(aoi) = "EPSG:4326"

I have tried the code suggested under the following link: https://rdrr.io/cran/gfcanalysis/src/R/calc_gfc_tiles.R. However, this leads to the output "Error in check_aoi(aoi) : function "check_aoi" could not be found" even though I have attached the gfcanalysis package, which includes this function.
Does anyone know what else I can try, or what I'm doing wrong?

Did you accidentally copy/paste the code from that documentation web page and hence override that code from the package? check_aoi is an internal function that only works from package code. Start from a clean R workspace and try again.

First of all, gfcanalysis::calc_gfc_tiles(aoi) does not return an error but a warning. You're still getting a result but are informed that there was an crs mismatch which has been solved (but you probably should handle this explicitly yourself next time to have control over this).
tiles <- calc_gfc_tiles(aoi)
#> Warning in calc_gfc_tiles(aoi): aoi and gfc do not have identical crs. aoi will be reprojected for analysis, 
#>               but may not overlap with results when plotting
tiles
#> Simple feature collection with 5 features and 0 fields
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 90 ymin: 0 xmax: 110 ymax: 30
#> Geodetic CRS:  +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs
#>                         geometry
#> 1 POLYGON ((90 20, 90 30, 100...
#> 2 POLYGON ((100 20, 100 30, 1...
#> 3 POLYGON ((90 10, 90 20, 100...
#> 4 POLYGON ((100 10, 100 20, 1...
#> 5 POLYGON ((90 0, 90 10, 100 ...

Second, I'm not 100 % sure about the underlying details here, but plot() seems to misalign simple features sometimes and this is exactly what happened here. With reset = FALSE, both layers seem to be plotted properly in terms of georeference:
plot(tiles, border = "red", reset = FALSE)
plot(aoi, add = TRUE)


You can also inspect positioning using e.g. {mapview} and/or {ggplot2}:
library(mapview)
mapview(tiles)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = tiles, aes(col = "red")) +
  geom_sf(data = sf::st_as_sf(aoi))

Third, raster::getData() also returns a warning, so maybe you'd like to address this in the near future to substitute sp's SpatialPolygonsDataFrame object by terra's SpatVector:
aoi_1 <- getData("GADM", country = "MMR", level = 0)
#> Warning in getData("GADM", country = "MMR", level = 0): getData will be removed in a future version of raster. 
#> Please use the geodata package instead.
aoi_1
#> class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
#> features    : 1 
#> extent      : 92.1725, 101.1768, 8.824445, 28.54326  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs         : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#> variables   : 2
#> names       : GID_0,  NAME_0 
#> value       :   MMR, Myanmar

aoi_2 <- geodata::gadm("MMR", level = 0, path = tempdir())
aoi_2
#>  class       : SpatVector 
#>  geometry    : polygons 
#>  dimensions  : 1, 2  (geometries, attributes)
#>  extent      : 92.1725, 101.1768, 8.824445, 28.54326  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#>  coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#>  names       : GID_0 COUNTRY
#>  type        : <chr>   <chr>
#>  values      :   MMR Myanmar

And last, check_aoi() is not an exported function from the {gfcanalysis} package - but can be accessed like this: gfcanalysis:::check_aoi().
